# Using Apache Tomcat with IntelliJ on Windows

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

My updated IntelliJ on Windows has following list of available servers (in `Run -> Edit Configuration`):
[image]

I want to use Tomcat, which I have installed on Windows. I've seen many tutorials on the internet, where people have Tomcat on this list. My IntelliJ is updated, Windows Service with Tomcat is running. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure Tomcat plug-in is enabled:

[image: Tomcat]

Comment: I feel kinda dumb right now... I was only searching in all plugins, not installed and not enabled ones. Thank you!